# Proving continuity of function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$
f( \, (s,t) \, ) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{s \, t \, \sqrt{t}}{s^2 + t^2}, & \text{if $(s,t) \neq (0,0)$,}  \\[6pt]
0,                       & \text{if $(s,t) = (0,0)$.}
\end{cases}
$

I want to prove that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

My proof:

Let $\delta > 0$ so that $\left|(s,t)-(0,0)\right|=\sqrt{s^2+t^2}<\delta$, and define $\varepsilon:= (2\delta^2)^{1/4}$. Now,
$$
\left|\frac{st\sqrt{t}}{s^2+t^2}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{s^2}\sqrt{t}\sqrt{t^2}}{s^2+t^2}\right|\le \left|\frac{\sqrt{t}(s^2+t^2)}{s^2+t^2}\right|=\sqrt{t}.
$$
Now, since $\delta^2>s^2+t^2$, $\sqrt{t}<\sqrt[4]{\delta^2+s^2}\le\sqrt[4]{\delta^2+s^2+t^2}<\sqrt[4]{2\delta^2}=\varepsilon$. Hence, $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Do you think this is correct?

Another approach might have to do with the definition of the derivative, but I don't think that would be a better/easier approach.

Comment: So suppose $\epsilon >0.$ You claimed that we should pick $\delta=\frac{\epsilon^2}{\sqrt{2}}.$ If $||(s,t)-(0,0)||<\delta,$  then is it necessarily true that $|f(s,t)-0|< \epsilon$ ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik I think that's what I've shown. Am I not seeing your point?

Comment: you probably mean $\sqrt{|t|}\leq (\delta^2+s^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ in your estimate

Comment: @JJR no, it's $\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: also your function is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Which point is it not defined for?

Comment: $\sqrt{t}$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$

Comment: True, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: Well it has to if you define $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @JJR You're right, there was an error in the text, so it should be $\sqrt{|t|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the function $f(x,y)=\frac{xy \sqrt{y}}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

Put $x=r\cos{ \theta}$ and $y=r \sin{\theta}$

Thus $\lim_{r \longrightarrow 0}f(r\cos{ \theta},r \sin{\theta})= \lim_{r \longrightarrow 0} \frac{r^2 \sqrt{r}\cos{\theta} \sin{\theta}}{r^2}=0$

Thus $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ (the fact that $y$ is non negative does not create a problem in this proof)

Now if you want to prove the continuity of $f$ with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition the you can use the fact that  $\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{\sqrt{y^2}} \leqslant \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\sqrt{\delta}$ and choose $\delta=\epsilon^2$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please point out the error(s) in my proof?

Comment: No i do not see an error in your proof..i just pointed out an easier approach to your problem.